# Powershell Filter Tab-Delimited Text File

Tags: powershell

I've got a tab-delimited file that I'm running thru a foreach loop to match values.

```
foreach($mvalue in $mvalues) {
$vName = $mvalue.Name
$filter = "`"" + $vName + "/``t`""
$mMatch = gc d:\test.txt | select-string $filter
Write-Output $vName
Write-Output $filter
Write-Output $mMatch }
```

$mMatch is not outputting even though $filter is correct and I can do a test in the console with $filter's value and it will give me results. It might be important to mention that not all lines match the value that I'm searching for; but there are some that do and for those I would like it to output the value. I'm running 2.0 on Windows 2003.

Comment: Can you give a small sample of test.txt that shows a line that would match and one that wouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to csv format and give columns a meaningful name:

```
Get-Content TabDlimited.txt | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header col1,col2,col3 -Delimiter "`t"  |
Where-Object {$_.col1 -match 'whatever'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar requirement where I wanted to search list of values in a field from a file, like in SQL we use the IN clause

> select * from table where column in (List of values)

Achieved using the following -

```
$lstExpenseID = @("VAL1"
 ,"VAL2"
 ,"VAL3")

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" -Path .\ |
ForEach-Object {
  Import-Csv -Delimiter `t -Path $_.FullName | Where-Object -Property "Cust id" -In -Value $lstExpenseID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write you filter like this (\t is for tab in regular expression) :

```
$filter = "`"$vName/\t`""
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always the little things:

I removed the parenthesis from around my variable:

```
$filter = $vName + "/\t"
$mMatch = gc d:\test.txt | select-string -pattern $filter
```

Comment: This is not fair play you just use my answer to build yours ! I build the pattern as I can imagine with your code, but the answer IS in the \t in the regular expression.